# Handling multi-address wallets in web apps

Tags: nami-wallet, cardano-address, webapp, eternl, lace-wallet

Regarding the topic of single and multi-address wallets:

1. What are the most commonly used single and multi-address based Cardano wallets? Are there any other single-address based wallets besides Nami or Lace that are live or currently being developed?
2. What are some strategies to manage multi-address wallet users in a web app? In my database I want to tie each user to their data by their wallet address, and for single-address based wallets there is no issue, however from my understanding some wallets like Yoroi and Eternl create a seemingly endless amount of wallet addresses because apparently in Cardano land you can make as many addresses derived from your private key as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding number 1.**

Single Address Wallets aside from Nami and Lace, which you mentioned, are [Eternl](https://eternl.io/) which have single address mode, and [Typhon](https://typhonwallet.io/#/) which allows you to convert the wallet to a single address. These two have my personal recommendation.

At the end of [this page](https://docs.cardano.org/new-to-cardano/types-of-wallets), you'll see a list of "other wallets" which has quite a few.

**Regarding number 2.**

There are many options to accomplish this. Something like [CardanoPress](https://cardanopress.io/) or [Cardano Connect](https://github.com/osc707/cardano-connect) do this for you. But if you are building your own tool, you can "getUsedAddresses" from the [cardano wallet dapp bridge here](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/tree/master/CIP-0030#apigetusedaddressespaginate-paginate--undefined-promiseaddress).